# Splitting array into two arrays from known item

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this

```
$a=["apple","ball","cat","dog","elephant","fish"]
```

I want to make a two new array like this from array $a . I want the things before dog stay in $b and i want items dog elephants and fish in another array $c

```
$b=["apple","ball","cat"]

$c=["dog","elephant","fish"]
```

I want to do this by using word "dog" not using value 4 . Is it possible ?
I searched many array function but my brain stopped working . So can some one help me ?

Comment: http://php.net/array_splice, once you've located the index of the `dog` value...

Comment: And [`array_search`](http://php.net/array_search) to find the index to split on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are okay with *array_search* function then it's simple. See the following approaches:

```
$arr   = array("apple","ball","cat", "deer", "frog",  "dog","elephant","fish");
$res   = array_chunk($arr, array_search('dog', $arr));
$first = $res[0]; $last  = $res[1];
print_r($first);
print_r($last);


$last = array_splice($arr, array_search('dog', $arr));
print_r($arr);
print_r($last);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the functions `array_search`, `array_splice`, and `array_reverse` to accomplish this:

```
$a = array("apple","ball","cat","dog","elephant","fish");

$lastItems = array_slice( $a, array_search( 'dog', $a ) );
$firstItems = array_reverse( array_slice( array_reverse( $a ), array_search( 'dog', $a ) ) );
```

There may yet be a simpler approach. But using the `array_reverse` method to reverse the array will help you get the elements sliced before the `array_search` element without using inverse directional slicing.

Also note that I changed your array initialization.